# Robot Framework: set logging level for a certain library

Tags: robotframework, python-logging

I'm importing custom library in my test based on some other python modules which are using python `logging`. In certain situations python `logging` inside python packages emits `ERROR` message which I would like to disable. The problem is I've tried different ways but all of them are not working:

1. Set log level inside custom library for imported python module

   ```py
   imported_logger = logging.getLogger('<name of imported python module>')
   imported_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   ```
2. Set log level inside custom library for both current file and imported python module

   ```py
   imported_logger = logging.getLogger('<name of imported python module>')
   imported_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   current_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
   current_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   ```
3. Set log level for robot framework

```sh
robot --loglevel INFO test.robot
```

All together these actions are not working. I still receiving `ERROR` messages from `logging`.
Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried calling the [Set log level](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Log%20Level) keyword?

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for the answer, unfortunately didn't solve the issue

Comment: It wasn't intended to be an answer, I simply wanted to know if you had tried it.